# RSpec does not see classes from /custom rails directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rspec

I've created my own service (which is Plain Old Ruby Object) in `app/services/nested/auth_service.rb`. Of course I decided to write tests for it, so I created file in RSpec under `spec/services/nested/auth_service_spec.rb` and wrote inside:

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe Nested::Auth do
end
```

I added `spec_helper` because `Nested::Auth` is just PORO without any rails stuff inside (so `rails_helper` would be overkill here, right?)

Unfortunately while running `rspec` command I got error:  `uninitialized constant Nested::Auth`

I added `$: << '../app/services'` at the top of `spec_helper.rb` but didn't help. `$: << '../services'` also didn't work.

How to let `spec_helper` see `/services` directory? How to fix `uninitialized constant` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow Rails convention and name your services with `Service` postfix.

This way `Nested::AuthService`. Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

In the pasted error message, the constant is misspelled "uninitialized constant Nasted::Auth" where "Nasted" has an "a" instead of an "e". Check any of your files for the misspelling and fix it if you find anything.

Comment: I changed class naming for question purposes and just made silly typo :) I solved it by adding service to class names (see answer below)